# Creating initial migration for existing DB results in empty migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 6.1.2.  I have an existing database, and I've Enabled Migrations. When I enter the command AddMigration InitialCreate in the console, the migration that is created is empty.  From what I can find researching, that's what should happen if I add the parameter -IgnoreChanges, but I'm not doing that.

Most of the Migrations documentation references EF 4.3. I haven't found anything that says it has changed for 6.1.2.  Is there a new command parameter to force the migration to contain the create code? Or is something else missing in my configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application is n-tiered with both a Web API and an MVC project. Because I have multiple start-up projects set, EF was not able to determine which application to use to find the start up configuration.  I was applying the Add-Migrations to the Data Access layer but the connection string and entity framework initialization settings were in the MVC web.config.  After I copied these to the App.Config of the data access layer, all worked as expected.